# How to calculate contravariant metric tensor from its covariant

Tags: general-relativity

I know that

$$g^{\mu\alpha}g_{\alpha \nu}=\delta^\mu_\nu$$

If I am given $g_{\alpha \nu}$, can I find all $g^{\mu\alpha}$? Looks like I only have 4 equations for 10 unknowns?

Comment: You have 10 equations and 10 unknowns.

Comment: You are right. I should have thought carefully. I missed the multiplication between different rows... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contravariant metric tensor is the inverse of the covariant one. You can then find it by ordinary matrix inversion.